# AR detect object change

Tags: android, image-processing, augmented-reality

I have am facing strange project requirements. Firstly, I have to detect a visual object which was done by using openCV library. Now, I have to detect change in size of object. for example, if object is apple and I cut it, it should show 20% of object portion is missing. Is it possible to do using any of the Android AR libraries?